# Excel single-click is activating cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse-click

I find that clicking on an Excel cell activates that cell, even when (I think) I haven't double-clicked on it.

Is there a way to change the settings for how you activate a cell as opposed to selecting it?

By "activating", I mean that the cursor appears inside the cell for entering text. So if I'm pasting data and click on the cell, I want as the top of the paste range, the cell activates so that I can enter text.

I haven't noticed this issue historically while using Excel, so I am wondering if this might be a systems issue to do with my computer/Citrix environment, rather than a software issue.

Comment: What version of Office do you use?

Comment: The version I am using is 2010.

Comment: Try starting excel in safe mode and see if it happens. If not, go back and disable add-ins.

Comment: The short answer, NO. Sounds like mouse settings. Try looking at your mouse "speed" on clicks. Also you might have set your mouse to double click with single click. I always use the F2 (Win shortcut for Edit-Cell) key because I dislike double-clicks. Have you done any remapping or AHK recently?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  These answers were correct and the replacement with a different mouse appears to have resolved the issue.  I haven't encountered deteriorating performance of a mouse before, but I suppose it's possible.